# Product Search by ZIp Code Radius

Tags: plugins, search, geo-data

I am building a marketplace that will allow vendors to subscribe and list products similar to an amazon or etsy. I want to implement a product search within the header that will allow customers to search for products and filter those based on a zip code radius (geocode). I am using WCFM Marketplace and the search form with Advanced Woo Search Pro. I am trying to do so without limiting to store locator plugins. I wrote a code to try and filter search results within the product archive based on zip radius, yet that code kept causing a critical error. Is there any existing plugin that I can utilize for geo location and product search? I am only finding one or the other. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code. Show the complete error from the error log.  Asking just for plugin advice can result in your question beieng closed.